# Global Kronecker-Weber Theorem implies local one

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

By [this note](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2015fa/LectureNotes19.pdf), the author claimed the two versions of Kronecker-Weber are equivalent (Proposition 19.3).

In the first part, he prove the global version implies the local version. However, he cited another corollary in his note which seems not applicable to me in this case:

> For every finite Galois extension $\hat L/\hat K$ of local fields there is a corresponding Galois extension of global fields $L/K$ and an absolute value $|\cdot|$ on $L$ such that $\hat L$ is the completion of $L$ with respect to $|\cdot|$, $\hat K$ is the completion of $K$ with respect to the restriction of $|\cdot|$ to $K$, and $\mathrm{Gal}(\hat L/\hat K)\cong\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$.

In this corollary, the base field $K$ is also changing. It might not be able to choose $K=\mathbb Q$, so it seems the argument does not quite work?

Comment: This equivalence for finite abelian extensions of $\mathbf Q$ and all $\mathbf Q_v$'s is explained early in one of the last chapters (titled "The Kronecker-Weber Theorem") of Washington's book on cyclotomic fields. Consider looking at the argument there if you're not satisfied by the note you are reading.

Comment: @KCd Thank you for the reference. Probably the note had some flaw there. In the new version, they removed the argument and only prove the local one implies the global one.